# How to find equality of 2 edges in an undirected Graph?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

Using boost graph library, I have this type of graph:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,                                //OutEdgeList
    boost::vecS,                                //VertexList
    boost::undirectedS                  //Directed
> Graph;
```

and add several 2 edges:

```
boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
boost::add_edge(1, 0, g);
boost::add_edge(2, 4, g);
boost::add_edge(4, 3, g);
boost::add_edge(3, 1, g);
```

I want to check the "equality" of the 2 egdes: 0-1 and 1-0.

I need a starting point for the implementation.

Thank you

Comment: why do you think you need it? You can just use `boost::setS` for the OutEdgeList, and no duplicates can arise.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is certainly not the most elegant. Here is what i did :
I put the vertices in pairs, complete the equality function and then check the pair equality.

1)put vertices in pair with:

```
std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> pairEdge( boost::numeric_cast<unsigned int>(boost::source(e, g)), boost::numeric_cast<unsigned int>(boost::target(e, g)));
```

2) complete the equality function

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    bool pairEquality(std::pair<T1, T2>  &lhs, std::pair<T1, T2> &rhs) {
        //standard way
        if (lhs == rhs) {
            return true;
        };

        //permutation
        std::pair<T1, T2> lhsSwap(lhs.second, lhs.first);
        if (lhsSwap == rhs) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

3) check the equality through a for loop of stack